# Generating HTML buttons with the same function, but different values in a JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to generate a grid of buttons, each button having the same onclick function, but containing different values (coordinates).  This would be easy in a normal JS file, but can not be done the same way in a JS Module.  I hope this makes sense ?

javascript:

```
let div = document.getElementById("divId");
let innerHtml = "";

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  for(var k = 0; k < 2; k++){
  let coordinate = JSON.stringify({x:k, y:i});
  let button = "<button id:'"+coordinate+"'  onclick ='logCoordinate("+coordinate+")'> "+coordinate+" </button>
 }
}

function logCoordinate(coordinate){
 console.log(coordinate);
}
```

Visually it would look like this:

```html
<button>0,0</button> <button>1,0</button> <br>
<button>0,1</button> <button>1,1</button>
```

And clicking the button would log it's corresponding coordinate to the console.

Again this would be simple, but because of the program being a JavaScript module the onclick function is "not defined"